# Dispatcher.Run generates Win32Exception only when application is run as published application in RDS

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, legacy, win32gui

I have a legacy modal dialog that I need to present from a windows WPF/C# application. It generally works well but under the specific circumstance of a published application in RDS if the user waits for a few minutes between the main application and then invoking the dialog it will crash with a rather cryptic error.

I would like to know how to get a list of messages that the dispatcher is running: if I could analyse the messages being processed then I could have a shot at understanding the underlying problem.

The actual exception is a Win32Exception. The Message is "The system cannot find the file specified". The HResult is x80004005.

The complete error text is:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetWindowText(HandleRef hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, Int32 nMaxCount)
at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.WindowAutomationPeer.GetNameCore()
at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdatePeer(Object arg)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.Disp
```

I have put break points at the only places where it gets the window text but that hasn't yielded anything useful.

The actual legacy thread is here:

```
public void InitLegacyThread(string config, string userName, string userPswd, double userLOC)
{
    _legacyThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            Application app = new Application();
            app.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri(XamlResourcesLocation, UriKind.Relative) });
            ClientServiceLocator.GetInstance<ILegacyMLDispatchThread>().Initialize(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);
            if (Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState != ThreadState.Aborted)
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
            }
            RegisterAppServicesAndEvents();
            _initializationSuccessful = ServiceProvider.Instance.GetService<IInteropAdapter>().FinishInitializing(config, userName, userPswd, userLOC);

            if (_initializationSuccessful)
            {
                BringPopupDialogsToFront();
                ClientServiceLocator.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>().Subscribe(this);
                InitializeCommonShellWindow();
                CreateBindings();

                if (Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState != ThreadState.Aborted)
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
                }

                // Signal the that legacy thread is now ready
                ClientServiceLocator.GetInstance<ILegacyMLDispatchThread>().SignalThreadReady();

                try
                {
                    Dispatcher.Run();
                }
                catch (Win32Exception e)
                {
                    ExceptionHandler.ShowException(e, e.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                AbortInitialization();

                try
                {
                    Dispatcher.Run();
                }
                catch (Win32Exception e)
                {
                    ExceptionHandler.ShowException(e, e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ExceptionHandler.ShowException(e, e.Message);
        }
    });
    _legacyThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    _legacyThread.Name = MLThreadName;
    _legacyThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you managed to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that one can do this by using the DispatcherHookEventHandler and HwndSourceHook. The messages that are processed by the Dispatcher for SDK type windows messages are not a one to one correspondence as I had originally hoped they would be. However, one can get to that point by adding a hook specifically on the target window.

```
    public static IntPtr MessageReader(IntPtr hwnd, int message, IntPtr lParam, IntPtr wParam, ref bool result)
    {
        _log.Error(string.Format("MessageReader - {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", hwnd, message, lParam, wParam));
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
    public static IntPtr MessageReader(IntPtr hwnd, int message, IntPtr lParam, IntPtr wParam, ref bool result)
    ....
        FieldInfo ArgsField = typeof(DispatcherOperation).GetField("_args", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Hooks.OperationStarted += new DispatcherHookEventHandler((obj, args) =>
        {
            System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource source = ArgsField.GetValue(args.Operation) as System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource;
            if (source != null)
            {
                source.AddHook(new System.Windows.Interop.HwndSourceHook(MessageReader));
            }
        });
        Dispatcher.Run();
```

This is strictly for finding out which window message is contributing to my particular issue. But in this way one can look at SDK type messages before they are processed from with in a WPF application.